# Group VM by tag in virt-manager on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, kvm-switch, virt-manager

**virt-manager question**

KVM on Ubuntu 20.04/libvirt/qemu
How i can group vm in virt-manager interface?

In virtualbox or hyper-v/vmware this is very simple. Googling doesnt gave the result.

Answer (score 0):

`virt-manager` does not support this functionality. It's more like `virtualbox`. `Vmware`, `o-virt`, etc. offer far greater functionality and orchestration. `virt-manager` is just a simple GUI to `virsh`, to allow easy creation and basic management of VMs. Very useful and handy, but with limited functionality.